# Display PublisherAdView with RecyclerView

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I need to display a few banners with `PublisherAdView` inside a list built with the `RecyclerView` widget and I'm not sure how to map `PublisherAdView` lifecycle with the `ViewHolder` one.

`PublisherAdView` documentation mentions three lifecycle methods:

- `resume()`: Resume a PublisherAdView after a previous call to pause(). This method should be called in the parent Activity's onResume() method.
- `pause()`: Pause any extra processing associated with this PublisherAdView. This method should be called in the parent Activity's onPause() method.
- `destroy()`: Destroy the PublisherAdView. This method should be called in the parent Activity's onDestroy() method. No other methods should be called on the PublisherAdView after destroy() is called.

The problem is that the `ViewHolder` could be created and destroyed at any time and its lifecycle is not tied to the Activity one. Plus, my `RecyclerView` is inside a `Fragment` and the latter has a its own lifecycle.

My idea is:

- Call `resume()` within `RecyclerView.Adapter.onViewAttachedToWindow()`
- Call `pause()` within `RecyclerView.Adapter.onViewDetachedFromWindow()`

But I'm not sure about how to properly call `.destroy()`.

Any experience with that? Any best practice?

Comment: did you find any solution for this question?

Comment: I do exactly how I wrote above and it works.

Comment: @RiccardoCiovati where do you call destroy?

Comment: @q126y unfortunately I had to write a workaround: I keep all the PublisherAdView in a `Set` created from a `WeakHashMap` and then I call the `.destroy()` method in `Fragment#onDestroyView`.

Comment: @RiccardoCiovati Just curious. What is the difference from calling `pause`/`resume` also inside `Fragment.onPause`/`Fragment.onResume` since you have a reference anyway? Do you have any thoughts which approach should be preferable?

Comment: @MyDogTom Well the Fragment lifecycle is different from the ViewHolder lifecycle. While the Fragment is in active state the ViewHolder containing the PublisherAdView can be attached/detached several times, that why I think it's more safe to pause and resume it accordingly. That said, I do not guarantee that my approach is the best one but it's implemented in our hight-traffic application and it is working without drawbacks.